# Compare click position with character positions in a huge image

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-cloud-firestore

So I am creating this project , In which you have tag the character .
Now currently I am storing their position as pixel but if user resize their window , their location get changed. I have a rough idea to store the position as % but I am not sure how or if there is any better way .
when the user click right it will show a contextMenu . Currently I am accessing the click location using `pageX` and `pageY`  and check the range with the firestore db .

code - https://pastecord.com/werizovoza.typescript

site - https://tribhuwan-joshi.github.io/Snap-Hunt/

Comment: Yes,use percentages - percentage of the amount left and from the top of the actual image. Then calculate the % of where they have clicked in relation to that image element.

Comment: @AHaworth for that should I first get the height and width of the image in current window size and then compare the click positions

Comment: And how can I connect the current click position `e.pageX` and e.pageY with characters position inside image. Since the click position will be relative to window

Comment: Find out the position of the image as well.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)